# How to make WiFi signal stronger on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Realtek RTL8723BE?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my HP Laptop. In Ubuntu the WiFi signal reception is very weak while it is very good in Windows 10.

I have **Realtek 8723be Wireless Driver**.

I have to use the following code in the terminal window of Ubuntu every time I turn on Ubuntu to make WiFi signal stronger:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Is there any permanent solution to make the WiFi signal reception stronger on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS ?

Comment: You could just add the command you want to run to startup, as shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/189995/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.04/).

Comment: @rajlego This is a wrong solution in this case.

Comment: man! that is awesome, you solved my wifi issue

Comment: You made my day, Abhirup. I spent 40 mins with HP tech support on phone and they have not heard the name `Ubuntu`, especially in 2017.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

This will create a config file to make the setting permanent.

Comment: Right now the code I have mentioned is already executed and thus WiFi signal is strong. Should I write your code without restarting Ubuntu?

Comment: You do not need to restart now. This command does not affect anything directly. It tells the system to start the `rtl8723be` module with `ant_sel=1` parameter on boot. It is exactly what you need. You used to manually restart the module with this parameter.

Comment: But you CAN reboot to check if the setting works. But I do not see a reason why it should not.

Comment: Reading more here https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/88, it appears that this is about selecting the right antenna for the Wifi adapter.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes here from google, as I did. It may help to substitute ant_sel=1 to ant_sel=2.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you want to improve another answer please suggest an edit to it. If you want present a partial alternative please repeat or quote the parts that are the same (in case the original answer changes) and highlight the differences. In any case don’t create a new *incomplete* answer! Thank you.