# Slow speed on Hotspot created from Ubuntu 16.04 with RTL8723BE Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel, hot-spot, rtl8723be

## History

I ran into a weird problem yesterday(on 13 Jan 2018). My Ubuntu was not able to get strong signals of Wifi. I once encountered this problem before and was able to fix it using [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872931/how-to-make-wifi-signal-stronger-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts). The solution was to make a config file as follows -

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

But this time it was not working. I found [this article](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/) and was able to resolve the "weak Wifi signal" issue successfully. It asked to download drivers from [this repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and install it using

```
sudo make install
```

Followed by executing these commands and then making a config file to make the setting permanent

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
```

---

## The Problem

But soon I discovered that the hotspot I used to enjoy created from my laptop was giving **terrible speed(of only around 0.5Mbps)**. The speed I get on my LAN is around **80Mbps**. I *switched to Windows* and found that the Hotspot created there gives Wifi speed of around **30 Mbps**. I would also like to add that I am using [Speedtest by Ookla](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest&referrer=utm_source%3Dstnet%26utm_medium%3Dmobile%26utm_campaign%3Dstnet) and the Ping in each speedtest is normal(in range of 8 to 10), which I used to get before. So there is **no change in ping**. I tried searching for this issue but was not able to find anything related. Your help will be appreciated.

### Related Information

> My wireless driver is **rtl8723be**

#### Output of `iwconfig`

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

#### Output of `ifconfig`

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:8c:fd:4d:1b:0d  
          inet addr:172.25.30.203  Bcast:172.25.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::90b5:2747:93a9:f969/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9004186 (9.0 MB)  TX bytes:14741038 (14.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:141049 (141.0 KB)  TX bytes:141049 (141.0 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:df:bf:8b:11:17  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76df:bfff:fe8b:1117/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12069 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8846 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13285506 (13.2 MB)  TX bytes:2959250 (2.9 MB)
```

#### Output of `lspci | grep Wireless`

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

#### Output of `route`

Here 10.42.0.47 is my device connected to the hotspot.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.25.30.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
172.25.30.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

#### Recent Software Update Log

I think there is a high probability that the problem is due to auto-update of some software. I am sure that this problem started between 8-11 Jan and it was definitely discovered on 13 Jan.
**EDIT #1-** I see that the **kernel** was updated to `v4.13` on `11 Jan`. I suspect that the problem occurred because of this update.
**EDIT #2-** I tried reverting back to previous kernel (v4.10) through grub and followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/593015/672640) which explains what to do when kernel is upgraded(or perhaps even downgraded). It didn't work.

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-05  10:31:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 2.3.1-2~16.04.4), apport:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 
2.3.1-2~16.04.4), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), 
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
End-Date: 2018-01-05  10:31:01

Start-Date: 2018-01-07  08:51:55
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 2.3.1-2~16.04.4), apport:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 
2.3.1-2~16.04.4), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), 
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
End-Date: 2018-01-07  08:51:55

Start-Date: 2018-01-08  16:34:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 2.3.1-2~16.04.4), apport:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 
2.3.1-2~16.04.4), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), 
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
End-Date: 2018-01-08  16:34:54

Start-Date: 2018-01-09  16:32:45
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 2.3.1-2~16.04.4), apport:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.2, 
2.3.1-2~16.04.4), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), 
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 
(2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-09  16:34:23

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  16:55:32
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: poppler-utils:amd64 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6), linux-libc-dev:amd64 
(4.4.0-104.127, 4.4.0-108.131), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (57.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 
57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), firefox:amd64 (57.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 
57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 
0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6), libpoppler58:amd64 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  16:56:08

=====================================================================
Start-Date: 2018-01-11  14:39:00
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2, automatic), 
linux-headers-4.13.0-26:amd64 (4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2, automatic), 
linux-signed-image-4.13.0-26-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2, automatic), 
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2, automatic), 
linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, 4.4.0-109.132), ruby2.3:amd64 
(2.3.1-2~16.04.4, 2.3.1-2~16.04.5), linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.10.0.42.44, 
4.13.0.26.46), linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.10.0.42.44, 4.13.0.26.46), 
linux-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.10.0.42.44, 4.13.0.26.46), 
linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.10.0.42.44, 4.13.0.26.46), libruby2.3:amd64 
(2.3.1-2~16.04.4, 2.3.1-2~16.04.5), linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.10.0.42.44, 
4.13.0.26.46)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  14:42:54
=====================================================================

Start-Date: 2018-01-13  15:57:28
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: rohan (1000)
Install: libllvm5.0:amd64 (1:5.0-3~16.04.1, automatic), libdrm-common:amd64 
(2.4.83-1~16.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: suru-icon-theme:amd64 (14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 
14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), libgles2-mesa:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 
17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), libseccomp2:amd64 (2.2.3-3ubuntu3, 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1), 
intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0, 3.20180108.0~ubuntu16.04.2), 
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), libgweather-3-6:amd64 
(3.18.2-0ubuntu0.1, 3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2), grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 
2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 
17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), snapd:amd64 (2.28.5, 2.29.4.2), squashfs-tools:amd64 
(1:4.3-3ubuntu2, 1:4.3-3ubuntu2.16.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (63.0.3239.108-1, 
63.0.3239.132-1), libxatracker2:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), 
grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15), libegl1-mesa:amd64 
(17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 
(0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), libgbm1:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 
17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), adapta-gtk-theme:amd64 (3.92.2.57-0ubuntu1~xenial1, 
3.93.0.38-0ubuntu1~xenial1), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 
2.4.83-1~16.04.1), grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 
2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 
17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), ubuntu-core-launcher:amd64 (2.28.5, 2.29.4.2), libdrm2:amd64 
(2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 
(2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), ubuntu-mobile-icons:amd64 
(14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 
(17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), grub-efi-amd64:amd64 
(2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64 
(2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4, 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1), light-themes:amd64 
(14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-artwork:amd64 
(1:14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 1:14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 
(17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 
(1.66.14+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 1.66.15+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15), 
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), 
unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.90ubuntu0.8, 0.90ubuntu0.9), libdrm-intel1:amd64 
(2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 
2.4.83-1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4, 
2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 
17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 
2.18.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), ubuntu-mono:amd64 (14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 
14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), libgweather-common:amd64 (3.18.2-0ubuntu0.1, 
3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2), initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), 
initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 
(2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 
(2.18.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-13  16:00:19

Start-Date: 2018-01-13  18:09:45
Commandline: apt install papirus-icon-theme
Requested-By: rohan (1000)
Install: libreoffice-style-papirus:amd64 (20170914-44+pkg3~ubuntu16.04.1, automatic), 
papirus-icon-theme:amd64 (20180113-2047+pkg17~ubuntu16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-13  18:10:12

Start-Date: 2018-01-13  18:14:39
Commandline: apt-get install arc-theme
Requested-By: rohan (1000)
Install: gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (3.18.0-2ubuntu1, automatic), 
gnome-themes-standard-data:amd64 (3.18.0-2ubuntu1, automatic), arc-theme:amd64 
(1488477732.766ae1a-0)
End-Date: 2018-01-13  18:14:43

Start-Date: 2018-01-13  21:22:41
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: rohan (1000)
Remove: linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1), 
linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1), libllvm4.0:amd64 
(1:4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.2), linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic:amd64 
(4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1), linux-headers-4.10.0-40:amd64 (4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1), 
linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-13  21:24:20
```

Comment: are you using your computer as an acess point where other devices connect to it.

Comment: Yes, I am using AP mode.

Answer (score 4):

I think that wifi power management is responsible for the slow speeds, it can be disabled with

```
echo "options rtl8723be ips=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: Tried it. Now Power Management is off but the problem still persists.

Comment: Is your hotspot using AP mode rather than ad-hoc.  I would also use WPA2 encrytpion

Comment: Yes, my Hotspot is using `AP mode` and I am using `WPA & WPA2 Personal`encryption.

Comment: I tried creating an `adhoc` connection but my device won't connect to it.

Comment: I made some changes since you answered.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/w-lan-geht-nicht-auf-laptop-bzw-hat-starke-sch/#post-8108483 (German Forum) the cause might be a setting that you can check and reset.

To check use `modinfo -F parm rtl8723be`

The output should look like this:

```
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware]) (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open) (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open) (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0) (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0) (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0) (int)
```

The last line is the interesting one. You can change the value of `ant_sel` from 0 to 1 to 2. Reboot and check. - You have to try and find out the correct value on your own.

```
echo "options rtl8723be swenc=1 fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

I dont know if this resolves your problem, but you could give it a try.

Comment: I have `ant_sel=2` in a config file. Reducing it results in a weaker signal strength of Wifis that are detected and hotspots that are created. Also, I tried experimenting with other variables but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

Check your entropy available:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

from an [arch wiki on haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged#List_available_entropy) and entropy:

> If [entropy] is rather low (<1000), you should probably install
>   haveged. Otherwise cryptographic applications will block until there
>   is enough entropy available, which eg. could result in slow wlan
>   speed, if your server is a Software access point.

Install haveged:

```
sudo apt install haveged
```

Check your wifi speed then start haveged:

```
sudo service haveged start
```

Now start your AP and check the speed again. Hopefully your issue should be resolved

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this. Thank you. Although my entropy is 3733. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

## Antennae #2 used to be the solution

Looking back through github bug reports, setting your Wifi to use **Antennae #2** used to be the solution on kernels >= to 4.12. One person found success switching it back to [Antennae #1](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/259) under kernel 4.13:

> Ah yes, after finding that my kernel loads a firmware that it didn't
>   before (`rtl8723befw_36.bin` instead of the regular one) i found this
>   issue, very glad!
>
> As far as i see it, 4.13.7 already includes the patch so no action to
>   be made there. in `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` i used to have
>
> ```
> options rtl8723be fwlps=0
> options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
> ```
>
> But now i need to `ant_sel=1` for a good signal. took me quite a long
>   time figuring this out.

Lots of [reports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948) when Ubuntu HWE (Hardware Enablement Stack) took users from Kernel `4.10` branch to kernel `4.13` branch around January 11, 2018. As far as your attempts to downgrade to kernel `4.10` some have had success. Others report success manually installing kernel `4.14` for RTL non-WiFi problems. Still others stayed on 4.13 kernel branch and used `rmmod` and `modprobe` as temporary fixes.

## Turn off Network Manager WiFi Power saving

Network Manager Power Saving may be enabled by default. Someone reports disabling it improves speed. Look into the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`:

```
[connection]
#wifi.powersave = 3
# Slow speed fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670041
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Commenting out `powersave = 3` and using `powersave = 2` disables power saving.

All the [available options](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55) are:

- NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT (**0**): *use the default value*
- NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE (**1**): *don't touch existing setting*
- NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE (**2**): *disable powersave*
- NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE (**3**): *enable powersave*

## Turn off ALL WiFi Power Saving

There are [three areas](https://selivan.github.io/2017/01/25/linux-4.4-realtek-RTL8723BE-wifi-fix-hanging.html) of power saving. To turn off all three use:

```
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/options-rtl8723be.conf <<EOF
options rtl8723be ips=0 swlps=0 fwlps=0
EOF
```

## Don't download and `make` old drivers

At one time you had to download source code and `make` the drivers yourself. This is no [longer necessary](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#rtl8723ae.2F):

> The rtl8723ae and rtl8723be modules are included in the mainline Linux
>   kernel.

If you are using [DKMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) make sure it's not recompiling an old driver with every kernel update.

Comment: Before upgrading to 4.13, I used to have `options rtl8723be ant_sel=1` in my config file. Then since I upgraded, I was receiving weak wifi signals, so I installed drivers and used a value of 2. It fixed my weak wifi signals issue, but the speed of hotspot was still terrible. Should I try to install v4.14 manually? Is it in beta?

Comment: Version 4.14 has been out for a long time (in weekly software years). I was running **4.14.13** for a week and **4.14.14** just came out today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/997861/why-was-kernel-4-9-77-released-but-not-kernel-4-14-14?noredirect=1#comment1612751_997861 That said sometimes changes in `github` fix WiFi bugs that don't get to upstream kernel for weeks if not months. Also kernel version 4.15 is the new release candidate (beta) which will probably be used by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: @RohanBhatia I've added another option to disable WiFi power saving.

Comment: @Jeremy31 already suggested turning off the power saving mode. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: Why do old kernels still receive updates? Shouldn't an update mean that users get themselves the latest version? Should I try a previous version or newer one?

Comment: @RohanBhatia The older kernels do not get updated. I've changed the wording in the link. Most times you find a bug report that points you to a specific kernel version to manually install. When a bug report isn't found I try a newer mainline kernel first to see if it is fixed there.

Comment: And the way to find a bug report is just to Google it? Believe me, I have tried it.

Comment: There are many `rtl8723be` related bugs out there I can only imagine how tired you must be from reading them. I've read lots for my old `rtl8168` driver and my new `ath10k_pci` driver. Did you notice the answer revision for **THREE** areas to turn off power savings?

Comment: sorry I was busy at school. I tried turning off power savings as you mentioned but it didn't help.

Comment: @RohanBhatia I added a new section to the answer. Thank you for awarding me the bounty but I don't think I deserve it...

Comment: You do deserve it. I have never used `dkms` and its not even installed on my computer. Although when this problem occurred, I did download and make drivers from [this repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) according to [this article](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/). It was of no use. My kernel got updated recently again, so the drivers would have gotten updated since then.