# Is it possible to get fast wifi with Realtek rtl8723be card?

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek

I know there's a lot threads about this Realtek rtl8723be wifi card and how it dropping etc. However, I got my card "work" and now I can at least connect to it but that's it pretty much. The connection speed is awful, fast.com shows **700Kbps** if I'm lucky. Should be around **10Mbps**

I have investigated this around a couple of months and done pretty much all the suggestions what people have suggested around the web. I have downloaded: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new and read https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/28 - which contains a lot of information about this issue including disabling secure boot, windows 10 fast boot etc. etc. etc. etc. and tested the speed with all different rtl8726be options.

So... after **months** of struggling I would like to ask does somebody, who lives on this planet called Earth, really have Realtek rtl8723be wifi card with a fast connection?

I really hope I'm missing something obvious and could get this work.

**EDIT:**
[Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak) - the question is all about antenna setting, which does not fix my issue. Have already tested the speed with set 1 and 2. Btw, I opened my computer and saw that the wifi card has two antenna wires, what does that mean? I have seen before only one antenna wire inserted into wifi card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak)

Comment: @pomsky see my edit

Comment: So you don't see any change in connectivity/speed after switching antennae? Have you rebooted after changing `ant_sel` value?

Comment: @pomsky yes I have, also have tested if there is any difference if I unload and load the card with `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be` and `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be` + I have tested by shutting off the computer because on some thread I saw that someone told that only rebooting is not enough. Not sure how solid that information is.

Comment: @pomsky on my phone fast.com shows 740kbps at the moment and my laptop shows 51Kbps.

Comment: Any improvement if you `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be&& sleep 20 && sudo modprobe rtl8723be ips=N`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for your help, sadly there's no improvement. It's weird that no matter what options I set to rtl8723be card the results are always pretty much the same. It feels like the main problem is not the card itself but something on my wifi settings or network manager maybe? I have googled what kind of things could slow wifi down but haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and run the wireless script, post a link to the results

Comment: Are you trying to use the RTL8723BE as a hotspot?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Actually yes

Comment: @Jeremy31 https://askubuntu.com/questions/995494/slow-speed-on-hotspot-created-from-ubuntu-16-04-with-rtl8723be-wireless-network has exactly the same problem that I have. Sadly, the OP never shared did he ever fix his issue, but referring to the comments, it seems like the problem occurs because of kernel updates at Jan 13. I researched more info about kernel updates and came up with a conclusion that maybe I should give a try for updating my kernel manually to the newest version. Is there any negative side of the manual kernel upgrading that I should be aware of?