# Slow speed on Hotspot created from Ubuntu 18.04 with RTL8723BE Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: wireless, kernel, 18.04, hot-spot, rtl8723be

This question is duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995494/slow-speed-on-hotspot-created-from-ubuntu-16-04-with-rtl8723be-wireless-network). I am running 18.04 and having same problems as that of the linked question that is my hotspot created by linux gives very slow internet speed on my mobile.  **The linked question did not have any answer** that's why I am asking this question again. I have ethernet connection which provides 80Mbps download speed. Also hotspot created using Windows provides better speed.

**Please** do not downvote this question. Either ask me to delete it or edit it accordingly.

**Related Information**

> My wireless driver is rtl8723be

**Kernel Version and other things**-

```
Linux puru-PC 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Output of `iwconfig`**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eno1      no wireless extensions.
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

**Output of `ifconfig`**

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.1.73  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 172.24.7.255
        inet6 fe80::5675:a79e:1107:813a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:5a:0f:2a:1e:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7078311  bytes 8373543554 (8.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2981  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2811337  bytes 295452598 (295.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 40240  bytes 3773824 (3.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40240  bytes 3773824 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b278:4297:4437:1448  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:14:01:66:72:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 56291  bytes 35741642 (35.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67298  bytes 88097804 (88.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Output of `lspci | grep Wireless`**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I am removed all type of power saving modes by using these parameters in my `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` -

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ant_sel=2 ips=0 swlps=0
```

I also used this command to disable powersave for wireless connections-

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

My entropy as given by `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` is 3742

**Output of `sudo lshw -class network`**

```
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 68:14:01:66:72:fb
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94100000-94103fff
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0a
       serial: 70:5a:0f:2a:1e:bc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=172.24.1.73 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
```

**Output of `lsusb`**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:50b0 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Output of `lspci`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

**Output of `rfkill list all`**

```
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

10: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**Output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware`**

```
[    0.032837] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.080030] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.435586] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    2.369155] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    2.381629] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   21.967208] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   22.297776] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[ 1380.179431] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[ 4132.061459] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[10383.619526] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[10423.544817] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[11441.006608] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[31225.151414] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[31567.860581] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[31587.048842] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[32189.414759] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
```

**Output of the difference of `dmesg` before connecting to hotspot and after connecting to hotspot **

```
[35243.538760] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35243.549651] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[35251.991517] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35251.991704] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35252.020276] rtlwifi: -----hwsec_cam_bitmap: 0x0 entry_idx=4
[35269.022094] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35269.042912] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[35270.151052] wlo1: authenticate with 1c:5f:2b:5c:e8:68
[35270.161140] wlo1: send auth to 1c:5f:2b:5c:e8:68 (try 1/3)
[35270.166785] wlo1: authenticated
[35270.168701] wlo1: associate with 1c:5f:2b:5c:e8:68 (try 1/3)
[35270.173415] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 1c:5f:2b:5c:e8:68 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[35270.173576] wlo1: associated
[35270.242194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[35272.761996] wlo1: deauthenticating from 1c:5f:2b:5c:e8:68 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[35272.828998] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35284.074902] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35284.075154] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[35284.177442] rtlwifi: -----hwsec_cam_bitmap: 0x0 entry_idx=4
```

I have tried to include as much technical details as possible by looking at the details of the [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995494/slow-speed-on-hotspot-created-from-ubuntu-16-04-with-rtl8723be-wireless-network). I will attach other information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may not be related to Realtech at all,
as I tried USB D-Link DWA-125 with same 0.7 mbps download speed
(by the way, upload speed is higher, between 2-3 mbps)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed with this kernel:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997

as long as you select antenna 1:

```
modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```